# Understanding the DAG in Spark Execution

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to understand the DAG execution a bit better while running codes in Spark. I do know Spark is lazy evaluated and that when we do any action (like count, show, cache) it runs the transformation commands.

However I wanted to know how far back does it go in DAG to execute those.

Like if I write the following commands on the predictions data frame.

```
sorted_predictions=predictions.orderBy(['user','prediction'],ascending=[1,0])

def mapIdToString(x):
    """ This function takes in the predicted dataframe and adds the original Item string to it

    """

global data_map_var
d_map=data_map_var.value
data_row= x.asDict()
#print data_row

for name, itemID in d_map.items():
    if data_row['item']== itemID:
        return (data_row['user'],data_row['item'],name,data_row['rating'],data_row['prediction'])


sorted_rdd=sorted_predictions.map(mapIdToString)
In [20]:

sorted_rdd.take(5)
Out[20]:
[(353, 21, u'DLR_Where Dreams Come True Town Hall', 0, 0.896152913570404),
 (353, 2, u'DLR_Leading at a Higher Level', 1, 0.7186800241470337),
 (353,
  220,
  u'DLR_The Year of a Million Dreams Leadership Update',
  0,
  0.687175452709198),
 (353, 1, u'DLR_Challenging Conversations', 1, 0.6632049083709717),
 (353,
  0,
  u'DLR_10 Keys to Inspiring, Engaging, and Energizing Your People',
  1,
  0.647541344165802)]

sorted_df=sqlContext.createDataFrame(sorted_rdd,['user','itemId','itemName','rating','prediction'])


sorted_df.registerTempTable("predictions_df")

query = """ 
      select * from predictions_df 
      where user =353 
      and rating =0
      """
items_recommended=sqlContext.sql(query)
```

Now when I run the following command I was expecting since it is a small query it should run fast. but it is taking lot of time to give output. Looks like it is going all the way to the top of DAG and executing all the things again?.

Which I don't understand since the DAG would have been broken when I executed sorted_rdd.take(5) command. So anything after this command would be executed and not before that if I run the following command now

```
items_recommended.count()
```

Then why it is running for an hour? I am using 60 executors and 5 cores. Sorted_rdd has 450MM rows.

EDIT1:

This is a follow up to David's answer. Lets say I have the following commands.

#### Sorting the dataframe

```
sorted_predictions=predictions.orderBy(['user','prediction'],ascending=[1,0])
sorted_predictions.show(20)

sorted_rdd=sorted_predictions.map(mapIdToString)

sorted_rdd.take(5)
```

Are you saying everytime I run the last command with `.take()` it will go back to the first `orderBy` and sort the data frame again and run all the commands again?. Even if I did `sorted_prediction.show()` to execute the earlier sorting command?.

**EDIT II:**

If I have a function like below:

```
def train_test_split(self,split_perc):

    """ This function takes the DataFrame/RDD of ratings and splits 
    it into Training, Validation and testing based on the splitting 
    percentage passed as parameters

    Param: ratings Dataframe of Row[(UserID,ItemID,ratings)]
    Returns: train, validation, test

    """

   # Converting the RDD back to dataframe to be used in DataFrame ml API

    #ratings=sqlContext.createDataFrame(split_sdf,["user", "item", "rating"])

    random_split=self.ratings_sdf.randomSplit(split_perc,seed=20)

    #return random_split[0],random_split[1],random_split[2]

    self.train=random_split[0]
    self.train.cache().count()

    # Converting the ratings column to float values for Validation and Test data
    self.validation=random_split[1].withColumn('rating',(random_split[1].rating>0).astype('double'))
    self.test=random_split[2].withColumn('rating',(random_split[2].rating>0).astype('double'))

    self.validation.cache().count()
    self.test.cache()
```

This function basically is splitting a data frame into train, val and test. I am going to use all the three later in a machine learning task so would be using train to train the algo and val for hyper parameter tuning.

So I cached all three above. However to make the cache executable I did .count on all three. But it takes a lot of time now for this function to work. Do you think all three need a .count or I can just do .count on one (test.count() and it would execute all the commands in the above function and would cache train and val datagrame too?. I feel that should work and unnecessarily three count is not required?

Comment: Attempted to address the follow ups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which I don't understand since the DAG would have been broken when I executed sorted_rdd.take(5) command. So anything after this command would be executed and not before that

Spark's lazy evaluation extends to storing things in memory. It will not do so unless you explicitly `cache()` the intermediate data. If there is no `cache()` call, Spark will need to re-process all of the steps before your `take(5)` call as well. To get around this, cache your rdd before the `take` action like this

```
 sorted_rdd.cache().take(5)
```

#### Addressing the Edit

> Are you saying every time I run the last command with `.take()` it will go back to the first `orderBy` and sort the data frame again and run all the commands again?. Even if I did `sorted_prediction.show()` to execute the earlier sorting command?.

Correct. In the below code, Spark will need to run all the steps to create `predictions` as well as the `orderBy` calculations to show 20 rows of `sorted_predictions`. Then it will run all the steps to create `predictions`, the `orderBy` calculations, and the `map` calculations to show 5 rows of `sorted_rdd`.

```
sorted_predictions=predictions.orderBy(['user','prediction'],ascending=[1,0])
sorted_predictions.show(20)

sorted_rdd=sorted_predictions.map(mapIdToString)
sorted_rdd.take(5)
```

#### From the comments

> I thought cache is also an action

Cache isn't an action in itself. It's an instruction to store the `RDD`/`DataFrame` in memory, but this won't actually happen until an action is run (eg. count, take, show, etc)